# xcode 6.1 Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working on a project and I encountered the below error on two of our test devices about halfway through the day today.  I've attempted to do the following to resolve the issue, but it still sticks around:

- Preferences->Accounts-> Remove Account-> Add Account-> View Details-> Refresh-> Restart XCode.
- Restart the mac
- Replaced dev certs and provision profiles
- Created new certs and provision profiles

The Build Message that is provided is:

```
CodeSign /Users/jlowe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MSIUAT-bmmhsvmhpevuxbalmdsygccqsclg/
  Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MSIUAT.app
    cd /Users/jlowe/Documents/PhoneGap_4.0/MSI/platforms/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
  XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
  usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iOS Development: JLowe"
Provisioning Profile: "MSI Development"
                  (81e07a7b-9a66-4d49-992b-688f1407c5a9)

   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 26BF4AC4B4E3560A8DD52AE7D6DE0B369326B226 --entitlements /
  Users/jlowe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MSIUAT-bmmhsvmhpevuxbalmdsygccqsclg/Build/
  Intermediates/MSIUAT.build/Debug-iphoneos/MSIUAT.build/MSIUAT.app.xcent /Users/
  jlowe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MSIUAT-bmmhsvmhpevuxbalmdsygccqsclg/Build/Products/
  Debug-iphoneos/MSIUAT.app

/Users/jlowe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MSIUAT-bmmhsvmhpevuxbalmdsygccqsclg/Build
  /Products/Debug-iphoneos/MSIUAT.app: Permission denied
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Any assistance that could help identify what is going on would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Also worth noting that I'm able to get the application to run on simulators.  My iPhone 4s on iOS 7.1.2 and another on 8.1.1 are both encountering the issues.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by giving permissions to the application folder.  I'm not sure why, but apparently some of the folders didn't have full permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by granting permissions to the application folder again.  Somehow the permissions to some of the folders had been removed.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem;  the specific command I used from Terminal was:  "chmod -R a+rwx myApp", where myApp is the root folder for your entire project.